# Checking for machine reachability on port 53

Tags: networking, tcp, netcat

I need a generic way to test the reachability of the server from my client.
I initially thought of using `netcat` command.
For example, I could use the below command to scan if `port 80` is reachable on `google.com`.

```
nc -v -z google.com 80
```

The problem with the above command arises when I have to check reachability via a proxy host. For e.g, if I have to check reachability to google.com on port 81 via a proxy host = dummyproxy.com via proxy port 80 then this is the command

```
nc -v -z -xdummyproxy.com:80 -Xconnect google.com 81
```

But, this command returns success for any random server/port combination irrespective of whether the host exists or not for a valid proxy host. I assume this returns the status of reachability to the proxy server only.

Because of this behaviour, I tried thinking of some other approach. I figured, port 53 which is DNS port is reachable on all machines even without proxy.
So my question here is: Can I rely on scanning port 53 to check the reachability of the host like the command below?

```
nc -v -z google.com 53
```

Note: I just have to check if the host is reachable...I am not currently bothered about which port is actually reachable.

Any other approach to my problem is also welcomed :).

Answer (score 0):

Host can be running one service eg DNS but not Http or vice versa or may be IDS Firewall silently dropping packets, I would suggest check multiple things using script python or bash.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Harry : isn't DNS service something that will be definitely running on hosts which require connectivity to the internet??
Sorry if my question sounds too basic...i am new to networking

Comment: DNS service is only running on DNS servers, You are confused because every domain will have its IP mapped and that DNS reply is generated by your ISP DNS servers or any DNS server that contains that DNS Entry.